# What does the phrase "There is still some meat to bite" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, usage, phrase-meaning

I was reading a review on a movie where the author was presenting his views on it. He used this phrase there to contradict himself; he said:

> This movie is about modern relationships and how seriously we take them but there is still some meat to bite on the theme as to how it portrays our solitude and distance from real life through being obsessed with social networking and stuff makes relationships non-functional for us.

Comment: Not enough context. Please add the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Voting to reopen (well, having answered myself, I suppose I would, wouldn't I? :) Seriously, I don't really see how any competent native speaker could ***need more context*** than OP's *"this movie is about.....but there is still **some meat to bite** as to how it..."* to recognise this idiomatically common usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The phrase "still some meat to bite" sounds very odd to me. If it were "still some meat to chew on" I might not have wanted more context. A link to the review would be ideal, because it might tell me something about the reviewer's dialect, but I would at least like to see the entire thought before I assume that it is a different phrasing of a common idiom and not part of a larger analogy.

Comment: Fumble - Although I agree there's enough meat here to provide an answer, I'm still concurring with @TRomano in that it _would_ be nice to have the blanks filled in. For example, if the reviewer was reviewing a vampire movie, there may have been some intentional wordplay to go along with the more idiomatic meaning.

Comment: @J.R.: The current text tells us *far* more context than any question I can recall here in the recent past (short of those that give us an actual link to the *complete* context). Not only do we know it's a movie review, and that the figurative "meat" refers to ***how** [the movie does something]*. We're also told the reviewer *used this phrase to contradict himself*, making it fairly obvious that the missing *_______* (whatever the movie's ostensibly *about*) must by contrast be something ***trivial***. In which case for our purposes here the precise details omitted are effectively irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

It's a figurative extension from *meat = the best part (normally, muscle tissue) of an animal's body when seen as **food***. Definition #5 at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meat)

> **meat** *solid or substantial content; pith*

It may seem slightly odd that the alternative ***pith*** in that definition has as its primary definition...

> [**pith**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pith?s=t) Botany. *the soft, spongy central cylinder of parenchymatous tissue in the stems of dicotyledonous plants.*

...since in many "food" contexts the pith would be the *least desirable* part of, say, an edible fruit. But that's idiomatic usage for you.

---

Personally I find the inclusion of *to bite [on]* in OP's citation at the very least "unnecessary", and arguably "undesirable". It's perfectly normal to refer to [*"the meat of the argument"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20meat%20of%20the%20argument%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) - but nobody ever talks about [*"the meat to bite on of the argument"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20meat%20of%20the%20argument%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22the%20meat%20to%20bite%20on%20of%20the%20argument%22).

Comment: It's not botany, but it's the **other** definition of _pith_ that coincides with _meat_: **pith** (n.) the essential or important part, point, etc. ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pith); also note how [_pithy_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pithy) overlaps in meaning with [_meaty_](https://www.wordnik.com/words/meaty)). I don't know this for sure, but I've always surmised that, because the pith is in the center of plant, it came to mean the center (or crux) of some issue.

Comment: @J.R.: Well, I don't really want to start arguing the toss with *dictionaries*, but I probably use (botanical) ***pith*** more often to mean [*the soft fibrous tissue **lining the rind, or peel,***](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_banana_pith) than the "spongy" stuff inside reeds & such. Etymologically, *pith helmets* and *pithy remarks* share common ancestry though. Perhaps the *strength, importance* sense came via [*pith and marrow*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pith+and+marrow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) (pith is/was also "the white stuff in the spinal cord").

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but it's possible that you're reading an English translation of the original review, or the reviewer is not a native speaker. I believe that the phrase intended was "there is still (meat/something) to chew on", which would have the meaning of "but there is room for argument on the subject".

Comment: I think it's an unjustified assumption that the writer is talking about figurative "meat" as potential material to be *argued* about. My default reading was it just meant stuff to be *thought* about (quite possibly in *wonder*, rather than contentiously). You may be getting skewed by association with *still plenty of **bones to be picked** [over]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - quite possible, but since I suspect the saying has been garbled, I couldn't rule out either possibility.

Comment: You might well be right about "translated, garbled". I found it (very) slightly "iffy" myself, and said so in my own answer, but I never actually thought "maybe it's a translation". Probably not though - more likely just a learner introducing a slightly non-standard twist to a standard idiomatic usage. But note that although *meat to **chew** on/over* is more common, it's just as compatible with *things to think about/be **interested** in* as it is with *things to **argue** over*.